# Sort list after lastname and than after firstname in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, compareto

How can I enhance my following function

```
personList.Sort (delegate (Person firstPerson, Person secondPerson) {
    return firstPerson.Lastname.CompareTo (secondPerson.Lastname);
});
```

to first sort after last name and than after first name?

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing to me. Do you want to sort by Lastname and then by Firstname? Or the other way around?

Comment: First by last name and if they are equal after first name.

Comment: you mean equal I suppose :)

Comment: sorry, you're right :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if `Lastnames` are equal and do the comparison accordingly:

```
personList.Sort (delegate (Person firstPerson, Person secondPerson) 
{
   if(firstPerson.Lastname == secondPersonLasname)
       return firstPerson.Firstname.CompareTo(secondPerson.Firstname);

   return firstPerson.Lastname.CompareTo (secondPerson.Lastname);
});
```

If you would like to use Linq there is also another way:

```
personList = personList.OrderBy(p => p.LastName).ThenBy(p => p.Firstname).ToList();
```

Comment: BTW: Linq creates new instance of `List<T>` but `Sort` not -it sorts existing list.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple:

```
var result = firstPerson.Lastname.CompareTo(secondPerson.Lastname);
return result != 0 ? result : firstPerson.Firstname.CompareTo(secondPerson.Firstname);
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ (only useful, if you can/want to re-assign `personList`):

```
personList = personList
  .OrderBy(x => x.Lastname)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Firstname)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Do I have to active/include something because he doesn't propose `.OrderBy` and so on?

Comment: @testing You mean using System.Linq